# C# Operator ? and throw exception

Tags: c#

I have following code:

```
public int Number(int x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x : throw new Exception();
}
```

The goal is very simple, with operator '?' I want to check some value, if it satisfies condition return that value, if not - throw some error. 
but VS Intellisense says: Invalid expression term throw; Am I forced to use other operators?

P.S. I guess that it's same as `return throw new Exception();` But still want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, that's not how the tertiary operator works.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this has been introduced in C#7.

Answer (score 8):

Prior to C# 7.0, if you wanted to throw an exception from an expression body you would have to:

```
return x > 0 ? x : new Func<int>(() => { throw new Exception(); })();
```

In C# 7.0 the above is now simplified to:

```
return x > 0 ? x : throw new Exception();
```

Comment: Is the latter just syntactic sugar for the former?

Comment: No, its syntatic sugar for:

if (x <= 0)
{
   throw new Exception();
}

Answer (score 7):

Write this instead:

```
public int Number(int x)
{
    if(x <= 0) throw new Exception();
    return x;
}
```

The conditional operator needs a common base-type to be returned, but there is none for `int` and `Exception`. In particular *throwing* something isn´t ment to be the same as *returning* something so even if your method would *return* an `Exception` (which was quite weird) this wouldn´t be possible.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Comment: Your workaround is correct, but I disagree with the explanation.  With `return x > 0 ? x : new Exception();` the compiler outputs "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'System.Exception'."  With the code in the question, `return x > 0 ? x : throw new Exception();`, and a < 7.0 compiler the error becomes "Invalid expression term 'throw'" because it simply doesn't know what to do with `throw` there since it wasn't yet supported.  The latter error occurs with `return x > 0 ? new Exception() : throw new Exception();` as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in C# 7. Your method could be further contracted to:

```
public int Number(int x) => x > 0 ? x : throw new Exception();
```

Answer (score -1):

With ? expression both sides must return same type, which is not true in your case. Replace with

`if(x > 0) return x
throw new Exception();`