# Re-throw an exception in a conditional expression

Tags: c#, exception, conditional-statements

What is the correct way of rewriting the code in the following `catch` block using a conditional expression? if supported!?

```cs
try
{
    return await _client.GetStreamAsync(_uri);
}
catch
{                
    if (IsConnected)
        throw;
    else
        throw new IOException();
}
```

C# compiler does not like the following

```cs
IsConnected ? throw : new IOException();
```

Note that re-throwing a caught exception, like the following, is in violation of [CA2200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2200)

```cs
try
{
    return await _client.GetStreamAsync(_uri);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw IsConnected ? throw ex : new IOException();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message on the `if` version? Im pretty sure the ternary is not legal C#; ternaries are expressions, not statements

Comment: Do you mean the `if` in the first example? if so, no, that works fine.

Comment: @Flydog57 `throw someException` is legal in a ternary, but `throw` is not, this is from C#7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209135/c-sharp-operator-and-throw-exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first example is fine. `throw;` will rethrow the exception leaving the stack trace in tact. As an alternative, I would suggest just conditionally catching the exception when `IsConnected == false`:

```
catch when (IsConnected)
{
    throw new IOException();
}
```

You can read more about the `when` keyword in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when).

Comment: Good [catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. For sake of completeness, would it be correct to assume that your suggestion implies that re-throwing an exception in the pattern I wrote in the first block, is not possible in a conditional expression?

Comment: @Hamed No, you certainly can rethrow it. For example: `catch (Exception e) when (someCondition) { throw; }` would work fine, as would more complicated logic in the `catch`.

Comment: Actually, I meant in a pattern like `condition ? throw : anotherException()`. Though I agree your suggested approach is more clear/readble.

Comment: I believe the `throw` part alone in a ternary expression isn't valid C#.